# C# Console.WriteLine Weird

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Here is a simple script in C# which outputs two different things. The issue is not about comparing the objects - don't get misguided. This is about using `Console.WriteLine` to send an output.

```
var a = "hello";
var b = string.Copy(a);

Console.WriteLine($"a == b: {a == b}");
Console.WriteLine("a == b:" + a == b);
```

The first `Console.WriteLine` outputs `a == b: True` and the second one outputs `False` which means ignoring the part in the quotation (`"a == b:"`).

I am using VS 2015 and C# 4.5.2 - tested with 4.6 still the same result.

Any idea about this behavior highly appreciated.

Comment: *"This is about using Console.WriteLine to send an output"* -- you got misguided. It's about operator precedence. Try `var c = "a == b:" + a == b;`. Without WriteLine, you'll see the same issue.

Comment: and what happens when you do `"a == b:" + (a == b)`. See also [Precedence and Order of Evaluation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx)

Comment: if you mean Console.WriteLine(a == b) - this says True

Comment: No, he meant `Console.WriteLine("a == b: " + (a == b));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second line is evaluating:

```
"a == b:" + a == b
```

And correctly returning False. I.E.

```
( "a == b:" + a ) == b
```

So the string is being built as `a == b:hello' and being compared to 'hello' as the`+`operation is done before the`==`

You can resolve this by putting brackets around the `a == b`

```
Console.WriteLine("a == b:" + (a == b));
```

Comment: While correct, this would be improved by some discussion of operator precedence and a link to MSDN. It's no good for OP to just go away thinking "WriteLine is weird, it likes parentheses For Some Reason&trade;."

Comment: OMG - yes, you're right I missed that expression. :-(

Answer (score 8):

The `==` operator has a lower precedence than the `+` operator. That means that first `"a == b:"` is concatenated(`+`) with `a` and then the result is compared(`==`) with `b` which returns `False`.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/

*Additive* operators are higher than *equality* operators, so they have a higher precedence .

You could force it with `()`, in the following code `a == b` is evaluated first:

```
Console.WriteLine("a == b:" + (a == b));
```

Your first example is using string interpolation where the whole expression is evaluated before `ToString` is called and then the result is concatenated with the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Your second line is 'string literal + a' == b, which will be false. In essence you are doing

```
"a == b:hello" == b
```

Which is always going to return false.